# How access key's value in the object in json file

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "001" : {
      "qwe" : {
        "num" : 52
      }
    },
    "002" : {
        "qwe1" : {
          "num" : 53
        }
      },
      "003" : {
        "qwe2" : {
          "num" : 54
        },
        "qwe3" : {
          "num" : 35
        }
    }
}
```

I want to store `Amount` their values,but I don't know how to access to them. I've tried

```
for(let keys in obj){
      const k = Object.values(obj[keys]["Amount"])
}
```

but it doesn't work, is there any way to address this issue?Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). I'm afraid it's not clear what you mean by *"...store all the keys (`amount`) their values..."* ?

Comment: Does each of the objects in the first layer only have **one** property within it? (That's true for what you've shown, but is it always true? Can we assume it?)

Comment: Yea it's always like this

Comment: Am I not seeing this or isn't there an "amount" property? Please add the full and correct JSON to your question or update it's text to explain where you get the "amount" property from.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've parsed the JSON to an object and stored the result in `obj`, to access the `Amount` property in each of the objects within `obj`, you'll need nested loops (either obvious ones in your own code, or hidden ones in things like `Object.keys`). For instance (I'm assuming here that the objects have no inherited enumerable properties, which is true of plain objects in normal environments):

```
for (const outerName of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const middle = obj[outerName];
    for (const middleName of Object.keys(middle)) {
        const inner = middle[middleName];
        const amount = inner.Amount;
        console.log(`obj["${outerName}"]["${middleName}"].Amount is ${amount}`);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    "08CcB9rs4GS019YNrzWTEG0W5ch1" : {
      "4vt4pqul4594ee66jkwelb" : {
        "Amount" : 5,
        "Date" : "01/02/2021",
      }
    },
    "08Db3T1AtRf5lzrBdg2yIEEuzon1" : {
        "3msj8caen59tlywi7xorz" : {
          "Amount" : 5,
          "Date" : "26/01/2021",
        }
      },
      "FeJ4wKdUcNPTW4LetRMIu1bc7zy1" : {
        "c5it14gi0w88ssldqqsaqe" : {
          "Amount" : 5,
          "Date" : "21/01/2021",
        },
        "kdei9yybz0eoiuvoepex2g" : {
          "Amount" : 3,
          "Date" : "15/01/2021",
        }
    }
};

for (const outerName of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const middle = obj[outerName];
    for (const middleName of Object.keys(middle)) {
        const inner = middle[middleName];
        const amount = inner.Amount;
        console.log(`obj["${outerName}"]["${middleName}"].Amount is ${amount}`);
    }
}
```

If we assume that the nested objects will always have just one property, we can avoid the inner loop by using `Object.keys(middle)[0]`:

```
for (const outerName of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const middle = obj[outerName];
    for (const middleName of Object.keys(middle)) {
        const amount = middle[middleName].Amount;
        console.log(`obj["${outerName}"]["${middleName}"].Amount is ${amount}`);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    "08CcB9rs4GS019YNrzWTEG0W5ch1" : {
      "4vt4pqul4594ee66jkwelb" : {
        "Amount" : 5,
        "Date" : "01/02/2021",
      }
    },
    "08Db3T1AtRf5lzrBdg2yIEEuzon1" : {
        "3msj8caen59tlywi7xorz" : {
          "Amount" : 5,
          "Date" : "26/01/2021",
        }
      },
      "FeJ4wKdUcNPTW4LetRMIu1bc7zy1" : {
        "c5it14gi0w88ssldqqsaqe" : {
          "Amount" : 5,
          "Date" : "21/01/2021",
        },
        "kdei9yybz0eoiuvoepex2g" : {
          "Amount" : 3,
          "Date" : "15/01/2021",
        }
    }
};

for (const outerName of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const middle = obj[outerName];
    for (const middleName of Object.keys(middle)) {
        const amount = middle[middleName].Amount;
        console.log(`obj["${outerName}"]["${middleName}"].Amount is ${amount}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values()` will dispose of the outer keys, leaving just the inner objects. They can be reduced to the inner keys and the amounts...

```js
const objects = {
  "08CcB9rs4GS019YNrzWTEG0W5ch1": {
    "4vt4pqul4594ee66jkwelb": {
      "Amount": 5,
      "Date": "01/02/2021",
    }
  },
  "08Db3T1AtRf5lzrBdg2yIEEuzon1": {
    "3msj8caen59tlywi7xorz": {
      "Amount": 5,
      "Date": "26/01/2021",
    }
  },
  "FeJ4wKdUcNPTW4LetRMIu1bc7zy1": {
    "c5it14gi0w88ssldqqsaqe": {
      "Amount": 5,
      "Date": "21/01/2021",
    },
    "kdei9yybz0eoiuvoepex2g": {
      "Amount": 3,
      "Date": "15/01/2021",
    }
  }
}

let innerObjects = Object.values(objects)
let result = innerObjects.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(el)
  keys.forEach(key => acc[key] = el[key].Amount)
  return acc
}, {})
console.log(result)
```

If you want an array of the amounts dissociated from the inner keys, make the reduce accumulator an array and just push the amounts.

Answer (score 0):

This works with your case:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach((k) => {
    console.log(obj[key][k]["Amount"]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. Here is the one:

```
for (const property1 in object) {
  for (const property2 in object[property1]) {
    console.log(`${property2}: ${object[property1][property2]['Amount']}
    `);
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/adamcai/czutdjgL/15/